# Javascript: Iterate Over Object with Redundant Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the best way to iterate over a JavaScript object (an array of values / more objects) where the object may have **redundant** instances of a property?  I'm fetching a database record which may have a role (the property) listed numerous times but with a different person's name.

The number of people can vary from record to record.  Some records may have one person while another record may have up to 5 instances of the property with different people listed each time.

I'm concerned that if I try to fetch the value to the object property that I will only get the first value found.

Comment: Can you post an example of your issue? It's a little unclear what the problem is from the text alone.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Property names must be unique, so if I'm reading your question correctly, that's not possible. If you have 2 people, they would need to be in an object themselves.

This is allowed:

```
  let myObject = {
    "people" : ["Joe", "Mike"]
  };
```

This is not allowed:

```
//BAD CODE DO NOT USE THIS
let myObject = {
  "people": "Joe",
  "people": "Mike"
};
```

Comment: JSON.parse and JavaScript seem fine with repeating properties and keep the last one.